# Select all rows but show the max value from the table in a new column

Tags: sql, select, max

I'm doing a select and i want to highlight any rows that have the most recent date. This is not per group but across the entire returned table.

I still want to retrieve all the rows in table regardless of whether they are the max or not, but i want to ensure that we can find the latest values subset of the table. Preferably a new column with a flag or the actual value in it.

How would I go about this?

Current table (example)

```
+----+-------------+
| Id | Date        |
+----+-------------+
|  1 | 1 Jan 2012  |
|  2 | 3 Jan 2012  |
|  3 | 2 Jan 2012  |
|  3 | 5 Jan 2012  |
|  4 | 5 Jan 2012  |
+----+-------------+
```

Ideal output

```
+----+-------------+---------+
| Id | Date        | Latest? |
+----+-------------+---------+
|  1 | 1 Jan 2012  | no      |
|  2 | 3 Jan 2012  | no      |
|  3 | 2 Jan 2012  | no      |
|  3 | 5 Jan 2012  | yes     |
|  4 | 5 Jan 2012  | yes     |
+----+-------------+---------+
```

Comment: what is the basis of saying it was latest or not and at what point?

Answer (score 0):

You can join the table with its `MAX`:

```
SELECT my_table.*, CASE WHEN date = max_date THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' END AS latest
FROM   my_table
JOIN   (SELECT MAX(date) AS max_date FROM my_table) t -- Note it's only one row, no need for a join condition
```

Comment: Incorrect syntax near 't'.: SELECT table1.*, CASE WHEN date = max_date THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' END AS latest FROM table1 JOIN (SELECT MAX(date) AS max_date FROM table1) t

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
SELECT ID,DATE,
       CASE WHEN DATE = (SELECT MAX(DATE) FROM TABLE1) Then 'YES' ELSE 'No' END LATEST
FROM TABLE1 T1
```

## [FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0874c/3)

Answer (score 0):

TRY this, I've separated the maximum date so it only get the max date once and used it in the main query.

```
DECLARE @MaxDate As DateTime
SELECT @MaxDate = MAX(DATE) FROM TABLE1 

SELECT ID,
       DATE,
       CASE WHEN DATE = @MaxDate Then 'yes' ELSE 'no' END Lates
FROM TABLE1
ORDER BY ID, DATE
```